# How to deploy existing DAPP to my private ethereum node?

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development

I am looking to build a PoC around a trading platform on a block chain platform. I am trying to deploy the dapp available [here](https://github.com/Ethex) to my local ethereum node.

Package contains:

a. HTML frontend part

b. Solidity Contracts

Please help me in making this in running state. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you get it solved?

Answer (score 0):

a) You need to get the front end part hosted somewhere. In this case locally hosting would be sufficient. Before hosting the front end part you may need to configure with it smart contract address and private ethereum network's RPC end point. For that you may need to follow the following step first.

b) First get a local network running in your machine using any ethereum client like geth with a JSON RPC end point open. Then you can deploy the smart contract in the private network: using the JS Console or remix IDE(Remix will be easy for a beginner) . Use the addresses of deployed smart contracts in the frontend app.